# Port Forwarding works locally but not from proxy

Tags: port-forwarding

I know this is a frequently asked question but I'm having some issues setting up port forwarding on my computer.

First off, we have a Airport Extreme. I configured it to give my PC (via my MAC) the same local IP address every time, namely 10.0.1.100. Next, I've set up port settings with following configuration:

- Public TCP-port 80
- Private IP-address 10.0.1.100
- Private TCP-port 80

I've confirmed that the local IP of my network card is indeed 10.0.1.100, and surfing to my PUBLIC ip address sends me to my website, running on my computer via xampp. I've checked with Xampp that it is indeed on port 80, and it seems to be.

Using a proxy however, the connection times out. I've added an out- and inbound rule in Windows Firewall for a TCP connection on port 80, and I've disabled my Avast Antivirus entirely, without success.

The port is definitely working, because when I go to `myWANip:90` or so I get an error that my browser couldn't connect, whilst `myWANip:80`, or just `myWANip` DOES give me the locally running site.

Since I'm able to access it locally but not from a proxy, it must have something to do with firewalls I guess.. Or did I set up the port forwarding on the router faulty?

Note: I've seen a lot of command line action in other questions here, but I don't really have much command line knowledge other than `route`, `ipconfig` and `ping`, so please explain things like this clearly.

Comment: Is this proxy server local?  Is this an open source proxy server like Squid or Apache (maybe with TS)?  Some clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Well I just tried some random online proxy to see if my local Xampp was accessible from outside my router/pc, but apparently not. (I used `webproxy.net`

Comment: This is a bit perplexing.  If you are going through a local proxy then you when you try to browse your website, it would be a DIRECT connection and you would use your Local LAN IP.  This is a typical proxy scenario.  If you have a remote client that goes through its locally configured proxy then that's a different story.  The remote proxy would make the connection to your web server on the WAN IP.  Have you verified that someone outside of your network is able to connect to your web server using the WAN IP?